# How should I install my own bash completion script?

Tags: 18.04, bash, auto-completion

I've written some software that includes its own Bash completion script.  This script works fine when I `source` it manually, but I'm trying to figure out how best to install on Ubuntu 18.04.

There are a lot of other completion scripts in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`, which led me to think that was the answer, but installing my completion script there hasn't had any effect.  Is that location a red herring somehow?  Or is there something I have to do to register the script other than just placing it there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could place the completion under your home directory in expanded value of
`${BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR:-${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/bash-completion}/completions`

or as superuser in subdirectory
`bash-completion/completions` under any of comma separated directories in expanded value of `${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share}`

The completion file has to be named same as the command, or it could be prefixed by `_` or postfixed by `.bash`.

You can run `type __load_completion` in bash to list the function that loads completions for details.

You have to restart shell e.g. by running `exec bash` for the changes to take effect in that shell.

Another source of information is https://github.com/scop/bash-completion#faq

Comment: That FAQ helped a lot!  The key part of this that I missed is that in the preferred directory (/usr/share/bash-completion/completions) the file has to be named the same as the command.  In my case, my software provides many different commands (scripts and binaries) so I was trying to cheat and write one completion script named after the package.  This doesn't work (unless it's installed in /etc/bash_completion.d, which seems to be deprecated).

Comment: @user161768 or you could create symbolic links to the file.

Comment: I like to chime in with the praise. I was able to not just add custom completions without polluting env by sourcing a lot of code at every start on Ubuntu, but also adding this to git-bash on Windows where the package content is not part of git-bash for obvious reasons (being that it is only intended for committing code with git, but people don't care and use it for all kinds of things instead of learning PowerShell). In case you are wondering why, kubectl and other go binaries which include completions (cobra). Can't praise the answer enough! Saved me a lot of time poking at the wrong ends.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to just copy (over-write) that file into place to `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` on your system?
Make sure you backup your original `bash_completion` file.

Then reboot (or perhaps simply log out and log back in again?) and you should be good to go.

See the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/984034/how-can-i-regenerate-the-bash-completions-file-from-bash-completion-completio?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: The file has many functions that other completions use besides it is needed in  loading other completions, so you should not overwrite the file, but you could put the completions in `${BASH_COMPLETION_USER_FILE:-~/.bash_completion}` for example.